# Difference Between default and new in case of Excel.Interop

Tags: c#, excel-2007, com-interop

I'm trying to open a excel workbook, but have a doubt in getting the difference between `default` and `new` while creating the COM objects.

I just want to know the difference between :

```
Excel.Workbook workbook = new Excel.Workbook;
```

and

```
Excel.Workbook workbook = default(Excel.Workbook);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should see [default Keyword - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25tdedf5.aspx)

> Generic code: Specifies the default value of the type parameter.
>   **This will be null for reference types** and zero for value types.

- `default(Excel.Workbook);` will give you null, since thats the default value of a reference type.
- `new Excel.Workbook();` will give you a new instance of type `Excel.WorkBook`